# Positioning Form Elements

Tags: html, css, forms

I designed a form for entering data, but for proper positioning of elements of the form  I use
"margin-left" with each element  to become below each other at the same position

Is there any way to do positioning better?

```css
#content {
  height: 200px;
  width: 400px;
  background: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <form name="log" action="insplacement.jsp" method="post">
    Year:<input type="text" name="year" value="" size="20" Style="margin-left: 165px" /><br> No of Company Visited:<input type="text" name="company" value="" size="20" Style="margin-left: 45px" /><br> Number of Students Placed:<input type="text" name="num"
      value="" size="20" style="margin-left: 25px" /><br> Percentage of Students Placed:<input type="text" name="percentage" value="" size="20" style="margin-left: 9px" /><br> Maximum Salary offered (p.a.):<input type="text" name="max" value="" size="20"
      style="margin-left: 4px" /><br> Minimum Salary offered (p.a.):<input type="text" name="min" value="" size="20" style="margin-left: 7px" /><br> Average Salary offered (p.a.):<input type="text" name="avg" value="" size="20" style="margin-left: 15px"
    /><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Insert" name="logButton" />
    <input type="reset" value="Clear" />

  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: You should use `dl` `dd` or `table`.

Comment: @Maddy forms aren't tabular data, nor are they definitions. You shouldn't use any of these elements for forms.

Comment: you a have witdh:1360px; instead of width:1360px;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Keep it simple

**There is no need to add any extra HTML elements**; let the form element markup speak for itself.

Firstly, give the labels a `label` element and a `for` attribute that links the `label` to its matching input via the `id`.

### A note on usability

Before we go on, there have been lots of usability studies – [here is one](http://www.uxmatters.com/mt/archives/2006/07/label-placement-in-forms.php) –  that suggest positioning labels **above** the input results in faster and easier completion of forms. Here I have provided both options.

#### Option 1 - Labels to the left of inputs

- place `display: inline-block` on the labels and inputs
- place a width on the label large enough to contain your largest label
- place a width on the form to contain your inputs and labels.

```css
form {
  width: 500px;
}
label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
}
input {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<form action="insplacement.jsp" id="log" method="post" name="log">

  <label for="one">Year:</label>
  <input id="one" name="year" size="20" type="text" value="">

  <label for="two">No of Company Visited:</label>
  <input id="two" name="company" size="20" type="text" value="">

  <label for="three">Number of Students Placed:</label>
  <input id="three" name="num" size="20" type="text" value="">

</form>
```

#### Option 2 - Labels above inputs

This is even simpler, one CSS property:

- place `display: block` on the labels

```css
label {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<form action="insplacement.jsp" id="log" method="post" name="log">

  <label for="one">Year:</label>
  <input id="one" name="year" size="20" type="text" value="">

  <label for="two">No of Company Visited:</label>
  <input id="two" name="company" size="20" type="text" value="">

  <label for="three">Number of Students Placed:</label>
  <input id="three" name="num" size="20" type="text" value="">

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#content {
    height: 200px;
    width: 400px;
    background: lightgreen ;
    margin: 100px auto 0;
}
```

and the HTML

```
<form>
    <fieldset>
        <div>
            <label for="name">Name</label>
            <input id="name" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="telephone">Telephone</label>
            <input id="telephone" />
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:-

style-

> ```
> #header {
>     text-align: center;
>     height:100px;
>     /*width:1360px;*/
>     background-color: lightskyblue;
>
> }
> #content {
>     height: 200px;
>     width: 400px;
>     background: lightgreen ;
>     margin: 100px auto 0;
>     /*margin-top:100px;*/
>     /*margin-left: 500px ;*/
> }
> dt , dd{width: 50%;margin: 0 0 8px;float: left;height: 20px;}
> ```

```
<dl>
          <dt> Year:</dt>
          <dd><input type="text" name="year" value="" size="20" /></dd>
          <dt> No of Company Visited:</dt>
          <dd><input type="text" name="year" value="" size="20" /></dd>
          <dt> Number of Students Placed:</dt>
          <dd><input type="text" name="year" value="" size="20" /></dd>
          <dt> Percentage of Students Placed:</dt>
          <dd><input type="text" name="year" value="" size="20" /></dd>
          <dt> Maximum Salary offered (p.a.):</dt>
          <dd><input type="text" name="year" value="" size="20" /></dd>
          <dt> Minimum Salary offered (p.a.):</dt>
          <dd><input type="text" name="year" value="" size="20" /></dd>
          <dt>Average Salary offered (p.a.)</dt>
          <dd><input type="text" name="year" value="" size="20" /></dd>
    </dl>
```

<kbd>[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/THE_j/v8omxjvp/)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Resize your browser to see this in action

**HTML**

```
<section class="feedback_form">
    <form action="" method="post">
        <fieldset>
            <label>Name:</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name">
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
            <label>Company Name:</label>
            <input type="text" name="company_name">
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
            <label>City:</label>
            <input type="text" name="city">
        </fieldset>            
    </form>
</section>
```

**CSS**

```
.feedback_form {
    margin: 15px 0 0 0;
}
.feedback_form label {
    display: block;
}
.feedback_form input, .feedback_form select, .feedback_form textarea {
    width: 95%;
}
.feedback_form input[type=submit], .feedback_form input[type=reset] {
    width: auto;
}
fieldset {
    border: 0;
    padding:0 0 10px 0;
}
@media screen and (min-width:768px) {
    .feedback_form {
        width:80%;
        margin:0 auto;
    }
    .feedback_form label {
        width: 45%;
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: top;
        font-weight:normal;
    }
    .feedback_form input, .feedback_form select, .feedback_form textarea {
        width: 50%;
    }
    .feedback_form input[type=submit], .feedback_form input[type=reset] {
        margin-right: 10px;
        padding: 5px;
    }
}
```

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hv9mrtw3/)